# Why does variational bayes use $KL(Q || P)$ and not $KL(P || Q)$

Tags: kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

In [variational Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods#Mathematical_derivation), we approximate the intractable posterior $P(Z | X)$ with a tractable $Q(Z)$ and minimize $KL(Q || P)$. Why do we not minimize $KL(P || Q)$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$KL(P||Q) = E_P[logP/logQ]$.  If you minimize KL(P||Q), then you would have to sample data from the posterior (P).  In order to do that, you would need MCMC or similar methods which kind of defeats the purpose of using variational Bayes (speed).  If you minimize $KL(Q||P) = E_Q[logQ/logP]$, you are sampling from your tractable variational family and only calculating the likelihood at $x$ sampled from $Q$.